# Warning! Impulse attack!

Tags: elite-dangerous

I was playing elite dangerous, ran into fight with NPC and then I saw "Warning! Impulse attack!" message. I googled it and people have different theories on what the message means.

What does  it actually mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Impulse attack means Shock Mine, Force Shell Cannon or anything else that moves your ship when it hits you. In my experience, these are rarely ever effective enough to actually worry about.

"Impulse" is a fancy physics word for "push" (force applied for some time).

Underneath the view of your own ship in the right of your cockpit, a small icon like this will appear when you're hit with an impulse attack:

[image: impulse attack icon]

Comment: I dunno about in the HUD, but here that icon doesn't look small at all. :-P

Comment: @Iszi: good point; downsized it quite a bit.